# Resolving a promise in a Socket.io callback returns a reference to a variable that doesn't get garbage collected

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, promise, socket.io

Here is the code in question. It functions normally except for two specific things:

(1) If I include the `delete b.x` and `delete b.y`, the function that uses this function's result errs when those fields are at that point `undefined`. I'm assuming this is because it's passing a reference to the object. Normally I would just make a copy of `b` and resolve with that, but that brings me to the next problem:

(2) There seems to be a serious memory leak in which I run the memory profiler on chrome and I see multiple GB being retained over many uses of this function. When I look at the specific objects being retained, `b` is clearly being retained even though the promise has been resolved. This is consistent with the fact that `delete b.x` is causing an error even after resolution.

```
const streamTrainBatch = (
    trainConfig,
    socket: typeof Socket
  ): Promise<{ x: any[]; y: any[] }> =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      // stream batch_size arrays and concatenate them along batch axis (0)

      const batch_ids: any = trainConfig.fileIds.train.slice(
        0,
        trainConfig.batchSize
      );
      const new_batch: any = { x: [], y: [] };
      let xs = [];
      let ys = [];
      let totalBatchesGotten = 0;

      for (const idToGet of batch_ids) {
        if (socket) {
          socket.emit("stream data", {
            dataset: trainConfig.datasetName,
            split: "train",
            fileID: idToGet,
          });
        }
      }

      if (socket) {
        socket.on("data", (data: Buffer) => {
          let [x, y] = processRawData(data);

          if (x && y) {
            //new_batch["x"].push(x[0][0]); // remove the batch axis (unitary) and... other axis lol
            //new_batch["y"].push(y[0][0]);
            xs.push(x[0][0]);
            ys.push(y[0][0]);

            totalBatchesGotten += 1;

            if (totalBatchesGotten >= batch_ids.length) {
              const b = { x: [...xs], y: [...ys], debug: "true" };
              //new_batch.x = [];
              //new_batch.y = [];
              xs = [];
              ys = [];

              resolve(b);
              delete b.x;
              delete b.y;
            }
          }
          return;
        });
      }
    });
```

How do I make sure that `b` gets garbage collected?

I could really use some help here as I've spent the past 2 days working on this and can't seem to get anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the socket closed when you got all your batches? If not, the `data` event handler is still around, and holds onto  `xs` and `ys`. Your memory leak has nothing to do with `b`, and you don't need to `delete` any properties. You should remove the `data` event handler and/or possibly set `xs = ys = null;`.

Comment: The `b` object itself will be retained by the promise, yes, but that is what you would normally want. You probably are storing it in a variable at the point where `streamTrainBatch(…)` is called? Look into that code as well.